# 3 functions repeat every 90min with 30 min interval from each other

Tags: javascript

I have 3 functions: 
   `TEST1`, `TEST2`, `TEST3`

I want to cycle from 1 to 3 at 30min interval every x Minutes. Currently `3x30min = every 90min`.

Cycle should be incremental not random and at fix set interval and with the first TEST1 starting when the script starts

I did not find any solution that would work this is for node.js and I tried using module repeat, for short interval minimum of 15min would work longer durations would fail repeating.

```
function TEST1(){
console.log('Test 1 Works');
}

function TEST2(){
console.log('Test 2 Works');
}

function TEST3(){
console.log('Test 3 Works');
}
```

Comment: If the only thing you need is to execute a certain piece of code at regular intervals, perhaps a system level scheduler is what you should be looking at... perhaps cron jobs.

Comment: Yes but crontab does not execute at intervals executes at fix time interval. Whenever the time = with time set it executes. Ex: if its 13:50 and you set it execute at min 50 will execute

Comment: This is not 100% correct. It is possible with cron jobs to define a job that executes every X mins. For example: `*/5 * * * *` will execute it's command every 5 minutes independent of the hour.

Comment: You might be right, I only tested out node-cron that was the result.

Comment: You could have 1 main cronjob that triggers some additional `setTimeout`. A mix between the cron job technique and raw code.

Answer (score 2):

Function `Test1()` starts immediately. Other functions follow having 30 minute interval between them. This process repeats in fixed set of intervals.

```
var cycles = [90, 90]  // Fixed set of intervals
var i = 0;

function start() {

    TEST1();  //Starts as the script starts
    setTimeout(TEST2, 30 * 60 * 1000);  // In 30 minutes
    setTimeout(TEST3, 60 * 60 * 1000);  // In 60 minutes

    setTimeout(start, cycles[i] * 60 * 1000);  //start function is repeated according to the values of "cycles" array   

    //Cycle incrementing
    i++;
    if (i === cycles.length)
       i = 0;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setTimeout(func, delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) to call a certain function after N miliseconds

```
function main() {
    setTimeout(TEST1, 30 * 60 * 1000); // 30 min in miliseconds
    setTimeout(TEST2, 60 * 60 * 1000); // 60 min in miliseconds
    setTimeout(TEST3, 90 * 60 * 1000); // 90 min in miliseconds
    // call main again to repeat the process
    setTimeout(main, 120 * 60 * 1000); // 120 min in miliseconds
}
```

But please note that @Lix is writing:

> If the only thing you need is to execute a certain piece of code at regular intervals, perhaps a system level scheduler is what you should be looking at... perhaps cron jobs.

Comment: Will test out and reply back currently for short duration (30sec,60sec,90sec) it works

Comment: Same problem longer duration does not work... I don't know where the problem lies

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var functions = [test1, test2, test3];
var interval = 1000; // Change to whatever interval you want
var index = 1;

test1();

setInterval(function() {
  functions[index].call(this, null);
  index = index === functions.length - 1 ? 0 : ++index;
}, interval);

function test1() {
  print('Test 1');
}

function test2() {
  print('Test 2');
}

function test3() {
  print('Test 3');
}

// Helper function for debugging purposes
function print(text) {
  var el = document.createElement('p');
  el.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Same problem, works on short duration, doesn't on longer ones.